# Method App\Http\Controllers\CD4Controller::importcd4 does not exist. Facing this error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I want to upload excel file to database table CD4 and I am facing issue this method can't find.

```
Route::get('importcd4',[CD4Controller::class, 'importcd4'])->name('importcd4');
```

Here is controller function:

```
  public function  importcd4(){
        Excel::import(new CD4, request()->file('file')->store('files'));
    return redirect()->route('cd4.index')->with('success');
    }
}
```

Need solution for that and I want to know why it's showing this error to me.

Comment: Are you importing the correct Class for CD4Controller? did you try another name like "test" for your function?

Comment: In cases like this you should actually go into your vendor folder and find the class you are looking for, there you can see the namespace it has so you can put the correct import!

Comment: yes i tried test class its also not working showing same error